# MongoDB Matching after aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of "items" which has in it a list of search tags.  As a user types in the tag field I want to filter all the matching tags with the count of how many items that tag belongs to.  I originally was using this query:

```
db.kCItem.aggregate(
[{$match:{searchTags:{$elemMatch:{tagLabel:{$regex:".*veg.*"}}}}},
{$unwind:"$searchTags"},
{$group:{_id:{tagurl:{$toLower:'$searchTags._id'},
label:"$searchTags.tagLabel"}, count: {$sum:1}}}])
```

This returns a list like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "tagurl" : "vegetarian", "label" : "vegetarian" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "tagurl" : "veg", "label" : "veggie" }, "count" : 1 }
```

Unfortunately this query also brings back the "other" tags (not matching the regex) that are associated with items that do match the regex.  My plan was to add an extra $match to the aggregation:

```
db.kCItem.aggregate([
{$match:{searchTags:{$elemMatch:{tagLabel:{$regex:".*waffle.*"}}}}},
{$unwind:"$searchTags"},
{$group:{_id:{tagurl:{$toLower: '$searchTags._id'},label:"$searchTags.tagLabel"}, count: {$sum:1}}},
{$match:{_id:{label:{$regex:"*"}}}} ])
```

However, when I do this even with * as the regex I get no returned items.

Answer (score 0):

The last aggregation pipeline should be

```
{$match : {"_id.tagurl" : {$regex : "veg"}}}
```

or

```
{$match : {"_id.tagurl" : /veg/}}
```

use dot notation to navigate to the embedded or sub elements